# Fully removing grids on a surface plot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a surface plot I've created in python using matplotlib, and I'm trying to fully remove the grid. I've used `ax.grid(False)` and that removed the grid on the background, but I'm still getting this faint white checkerboard pattern.

[image]

I've been doing some research and I can't figure out how to get this to go away. Any tips?

Comment: Two tips might be: 1) use the scalar parameter `s` of [`matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) 2) rather use [`matplotlib.pyplot.imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow).

Comment: @Baptiste oh dang it, I meant surface plot, not scatter plot. Just edited the original post to reflect that. I'm looking at matplotlib.pyplot.imshow right now though

Comment: The surface plot is useless with such a "camera position". You should prefer [`matplotlib.pyplot.imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow)...

Comment: Some code would help us understand what you are doing.  Also `ax.grid` controls the grid on the axes, you are seeing the grid coming from the Aritist.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. It was as simple as just setting antialiased equal to false.